# Regex for getting occurrences of a word in a string but not words containing that word

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to find matches of words in a string regardless of case, but not larger words where the target word is a part of.

For instance, if the target word is "apple", the regex should find it in the following strings:

> "I found an apple."
>
> "Apple, it's on the ground"
>
> "That ApPLE is nice"

But **not** the following strings:

> "Many apples"
>
> "Yellow pineapple"

I'm using PHP and I've searched around and found the following regex:

```
preg_match("\W*((?i)apple(?-i))\W*",$string)
```

But there seems to be an issue with it as I get the following error:

> Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

What correct regex pattern could solve this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `/` to delimit the regex. So a solution could look like this:

```
preg_match_all('/\bapple\b/i', $string, $matches);
$count = count($matches[0]); // group 0 are the full matches
```

The `i` modifier matches case-insensitive and instead of the `g` modifier we have to use `preg_match_all`.